# Getting reftex recomendations for labels when creating new sections

Tags: emacs

In `TeX-latex-mode` under Emacs (26.1) using the `reftex` minor mode,

- When pressing `C-c (`, the command `reftex-label` (found in `reftex-mode-map`, from `reftex-ref.el`) gives pretty good suggestions of label according to context for sections (with the default value of `reftex-insert-label-flags`).
- When pressing `C-c C-s`, the command `LaTeX-section` (found in `LaTeX-mode-map`, defined in `latex.el`) offers to enter a label for the section, with no suggestion (other than a prefix based on the level of the section, which is useful but much less than the one based on the title section offered by `reftex-label`).

How can one configure `LaTeX-section` to make the same suggestions as `reftex-label` for sections?

1. The hook `LaTeX-section-hook` along with the variable `LaTeX-section-label` would seem the right candidate for that purpose, but the documentation states that

> Some LaTeX packages (such as `fancyref`) look at the prefix to
> generate some text around cross-references automatically.  When using
> those packages, you should not change this variable.

for one, I assume that `reftex` is one of such packages, and second, I was expecting to be able to give a function inside a hook, not a list of prefixes, I wonder if I misunderstood what a hook is?

2. I think that one would "just" need to get `LaTeX-section` to abstain from offering a label and to call the function `reftex-label` immediately after each `LaTeX-section` call, but if it is not `LaTeX-section-hook`, I do not know which one it could be?

Before starting programming something which could involve stuff as complicated as refactoring both `latex.el` and `reftex-ref.el`, I thought I would ask in case I was missing an easier solution!!!

Comment: Interesting question. May you provide a complete code example before/after?

Comment: BTW: wherefrom the need switching off reftex-mode?

Comment: I don't switch off reftex-mode!